# How do I make the text tag width same as the visual text?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I'm wondering if there is a way to make the H1 tag the same width as the text you can see on the screen.

For me if I don't set a width to the H1 tag its width gets 100% and I can't margin if its so wide.

jsfiddle: 
    jsfiddle.net/PBWjr/

Comment: can you show this on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be like so:

```
<h1><span>Your text here</span></h1>
```

Then you can style `h1>span` as needed.

Comment: I did like you did but it still wont margin:0 auto 
here is how i did http://jsfiddle.net/PBWjr/

Comment: Why not just use `text-align:center`?

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right:

In order to center content you have two options:

1. To set width and margin auto, on left and right.
2. To enclose the `H1` in a `div` and set `text-align:center`.

here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anirudhvarma/54Ujn/

Just a note, If you want to use the 1st method don't forget to add `<!doctype html>` else IE will put it all on the left!